# inserting arraylist second time in firebase it is appending, not in the firebase but in my recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, upload

When I am updating my list in firebase it is updating correctly but it is adding same list below the previous list in recycler view. How can I solve this issue. I want list to be updated in recycler view as well.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: ExamAdapter
    private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var databaseRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var arrayList: ArrayList<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        databaseRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Answers")

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        arrayList = ArrayList<String>()
        for (i in 0 until 90) {
            arrayList.add("")
        }

        adapter = ExamAdapter(this, arrayList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("ERROR", "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                    arrayList.add(it.key!!.toInt(), it.value.toString())
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        })
        fab_send.setOnClickListener {
            databaseRef.setValue(arrayList)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time there's an update to the data under `databaseRef` in the database, your `onDataChange` gets called with all data under that location. So you need to **replace** the entire contents of your `arrayList` with the new contents from the snapshot:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    arrayList.clear();
    dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
        arrayList.add(it.key!!.toInt(), it.value.toString())
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```